# how to map enum values into different columns in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, mapping

I want to have fixed values for some fields on my DB, so I declared enums and I want to map them into the DB with that fixed values. What is the best solution for that?

Right now I've coded this (it doesn't work)

My table in the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sistemaFacturacion`.`formaPago` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` INT NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `plazo` INT NOT NULL,
  `interes` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `cancelado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

POJO Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "formaPago")
public class FormaPago implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -412540568702221226L;
    private Integer id;
    private FormaPagoEnum tipo;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Embedded
    public FormaPagoEnum getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(FormaPagoEnum tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public FormaPago(){}

}
```

My enum class:

```
@Embeddable
public enum FormaPagoEnum {

    EFECTIVO("EFECTIVO", PlazoEnum.CERO, true), 
    CREDITO_QUINCE("CREDITO A QUINCE DIAS", PlazoEnum.QUINCE, false),
    CREDITO_TREINTA("CREDITO A TREINTA DIAS", PlazoEnum.TREINTA, false),
    CREDITO_SESENTA("CREDITO A SESENTA DIAS", PlazoEnum.SESENTA, false);

    private  String descripcion;
    private  Calendar fecha;
    private  PlazoEnum plazo;   
    private  boolean cancelado;

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public void setPlazo(PlazoEnum plazo) {
        this.plazo = plazo;
    }

    public void setCancelado(boolean cancelado) {
        this.cancelado = cancelado;
    }

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "fecha", nullable = false)
    public Calendar getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "plazo")
    public PlazoEnum getPlazo() {
        return plazo;
    }

    @Column(name = "cancelado")
    public boolean isCancelado() {
        return cancelado;
    }

    FormaPagoEnum(){}

    FormaPagoEnum(String descripcion, PlazoEnum plazo, boolean cancelado) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.fecha = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        this.plazo = plazo;     
        this.cancelado = cancelado;
    }   
}
```

if you have some other ideas that will work better, please teach me how I'm new at hibernate!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Enumerated is fine.

Comment: yes i know, but i want to map the attributes of the enum to my table. So for example, attribute descripcion maps with field descripcion in the table